# How to set DynamoDB range key, String or Map

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a primary hash key, and a range key. Range key will have two attributes. Say those attribute names are: `name1, name2`, with values `value1, value2`

**Plan A**: combine two attributes as string, use comma as delimiter
Primary hash key: `id`
Range key:  `value1,value2`

**Cons**
1. comma may not work if some wired values contain this delimiter

**Plan B**: convert map as String for range key
Primary hash key: `id`
Range key: `“{\“name1\”: \“value1\”, \“name2\”: \“value2\”}”`

**Cons**
1. different SDK may result into different JSON String based on the same value? (Not sure), need to support multiple SDK read/write. Like Java and Ruby

So, which solution works better? Or there are any better suggestions?

Thanks!
Ray

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. The AWS docs regarding key design promote your first suggestion, but it also has some warnings about the situation that you refered as cons.

I don't think that you could have problemas with different sdk parsers, but I also think that a little bit of precautions here would be a good ideia. So instead of directly parse a json to string using the sdk, I would manually concatenate the values using a custom function to generate a deterministic value like "`name1-value1-name2-value2`" or "`name1:value1-name2:value2`".