# DynamoDB: Designing partition key from multiple fields

Tags: java, jackson, amazon-dynamodb

I've read the thread [How to set DynamoDB range key, String or Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803035/how-to-set-dynamodb-range-key-string-or-map). However after some thought, I came up with more consideration.

I use jackson for serialize & deserialize object in spring app. This app was created by someone else and it's in my hand now to enhance it after its initial release.

There are 2 options to generate the partition key :

1. Use delimiter ( e.g. value1#value2 )
2. serialize to JSON ( e.g. {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"} )

**Delimiter-approach:**
If I use delimiter, I can create a delimiter that very unlikely (in my case)  shows up as part of value1 or value2. This approach will generate shorter string than using jackson. Also the official DynamoDB documentation give example with this approach.
However this approach means I need to document the order and rule. In case other app (e.g. Node-based or Go use the same DB, I need to tell them to read the docs.

**Jackson-approach:**
If I use jackson, it's quite self documented, I can use `@JsonFormat` to maintain formatting consistency, I can use `@JsonFilter` to pick which fields I want to serialize for this case. I can use `@JsonProperty` to shorten field name (although I doubt that I'll need to shorten field name), and also the implementation will be more robust.
But then again, in my case there's already a table that already implemented the delimiter approach. It means that there will be two different formatting needs to be written on the app documentation. Also I think that a key generation should be very explicit.

I'm a bit pros to delimiter-approach for the sake of consistent formatting, but then again I might miss or haven't see the good things from Jackson-approach, especially in the future of this project development.
My question is : should I use the delimiter-approach or the other?